# iPhone app distribution in a club

Tags: iphone, ios, distribution, store

I am a member of a gliding club with 150 members, and we want to have our own iPhone app. Requiring a member login, the app would be usable only by members of the club, and it would be used by an estimated 20-30 people.

Is it even possible to disribute such an app to non-jailbroken iPhones? According to my research:

- It wouldn't be accepted on the App Store due to "limited audience".
- Even if we were able and willing to pay $300 for the enterprise distribution model, Apple would likely not accept us as a company.
- Ad hoc distribution would be fine for us except for the expiration time associated with apps distributed in the manner.

Are we at a dead end?

Thanks.

**Edit:** In case anyone is wondering why I didn't just ask Apple directly: I did, and their answer was, "We are unable to advise you with respect to the Apple Developer Program that best fits your needs."

Comment: Look into App Store Volume Purchase Program.

Comment: Thanks for your answers - all very good suggestions. Unfortunately, I can only accept one of them, so I've chosen the one that we are most likely to persue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% on your question.

But depending on your requirement, pretty much everything you need can be achieved as a web app, with the correct coding behind it i.e. CACHE MANIFEST you could make the app function similar to the a native app, available offline and can be saved to any iOS device through the browser.

Give me a shout if you need more information.

Hope it helps
Gary

Comment: I've thought of doing something like that as a plan B. We don't need much offline functionality; the app is for making purchases and registering it in our database (just to be clear, though: the app does not need to handle credit card payments). It would be nice to be able to save credentials, though, and perhaps launch the web app through a launcher icon. So yes, I would appreciate some ideas on technologies to use here.

Comment: With the likes of jquery mobile, html5, javascript/jquery this sounds like a pretty simple app. To be honest the offline functionality acts as a cache, the idea is the pages will not need to be downloaded everytime you launch the app so boosting the performance, the nice thing about this is that the app will automatically update when it notices any changes on the web server. You can assign logos/icons etc. so it will act and look like an app from the springboard. Local Storage is also a big help

Comment: Thanks - this looks like the best option in my particular case.

Answer (score 2):

You could always try to make the app a little more "global"? Perhaps offer some free stuff for Joe Bloggs to use, but tucked away you have your real motive... that way you can get it released legitimately.

I've seen some real disasters in the app store that shouldn't have made it, and I'm sure Apples screening isn't as intense as we might think. (example: that flash light application, when pressing a sequence of buttons it would enable free tethering).

Best of luck!

Comment: very true. Perhaps you should try and get some pointers direct from Apple. If you submit and its rejected, they'll give you feedback... then adapt your app to fit their criteria. (p.s still wish I had that app! Although I did read this the other day http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2011/09/15/apple-jew-or-not-jew-france_n_963791.html - I know its in no way related but still)

Answer (score 1):

Yup. You seem to have all the options laid out pretty clearly, and there's no other way to do it. Except developing for android, and just distributing the application freely and without arbitrary restrictions.

Sorry.

Ad-hoc distribution would give you about 90 days expiration time, i think, whereas enterprise would give you a year. Though gaining enterprise status in the eyes of apple is easier said than done.

Comment: Yeah, we already have an Android app on Android Market which, of course, was totally painless to achieve, but it leaves out the poor iPhone users. =)

Comment: If the same users were to reinstall the app after 90 days, would it count toward our total of 100 installations? In other words, could we achieve more than 100 installations as long as it's occuring on the same devices every time?

Comment: The limit is on the number of devices, not installations.  You can install on the same device over and over without problems.

Comment: Interesting. It would still require an active $99/yr developer account for users to be able to reinstall, right?

Comment: Yes. You'll need an active Provisioning profile, and for that, you need an active dev account.

Answer (score 1):

> Even if we were able and willing to pay $300 for the enterprise distribution model, Apple would likely not accept us as a company.

You don't have to be a company to apply for the enterprise account, you just need to be an organisation with a DUNS number.

Comment: Well, we do have the Danish equivalent of a DUNS number. But paying $300/yr is really not the way we want to go.